# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')

Tags: discord.js

I've been searching all kinds of answers for this kind of error but everything I try is either an error or it doesn't work.
Basically I'm trying to make a bot for my Discord server and have a presence status saying how many members are in my server. I get this error every time:
`` name: `${guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size} users!` ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members') ``
I already checked that the guild ID is correct, that I have no grammar errors and everything.

Here's the code:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("745807908071145564");
client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is ready!");
  setInterval(() => {
    client.setPresence({
      status: "online", 
      activity: {
        name: `${guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size} users!`, 
        type: "WATCHING"
      }
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  },5000); // 5 seconds just for testing
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out, using `activity` rather than `presence`, also need to get members from cache which is where the error undefined is coming from.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("745807908071145564");

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is ready!");
  setInterval(() => {
    client.user.setActivity({
        name: `${guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size} users!`, 
        type: "WATCHING"
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  },5000); // 5 seconds just for testing
});
```

If you want to use `presence` you can still do that too

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("745807908071145564");

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is ready!");
  setInterval(() => {
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: `${guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size} users!`, 
            type: "WATCHING"
        }
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  },5000); // 5 seconds just for testing
});
```